# How to Use Operators in C?

Tags: c

I would love to know how to write correctly the `if` statement using operators.

I want that the user will enter a number and the program will check which number is the nearest one that can be divided by three.

I know how to write correct the *else*, but the problem is with the beginning.

Thanks.

```
if ((n++)%3==0 )
{
    printf("%d", n);
}
else
{
    n--;
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

Comment: This kind of usage of the increment operator is quite misleading, you should probably just check `n` in the condition and increment it only if necessary.

Comment: If the number is expected to be positive you should state that assumption, otherwise it's more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Or just

```
int closest = ((n+1) / 3) * 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the `post increment`operator. Your code will work fine if you use the `pre increment`operator.

```
if ( ((++n)%3) == 0)
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: i can write it like this? : if (((++n) % 3) == 0|| ((--n) % 3) == 0)

Comment: Now in that statement, you are first checking if `(n+1)%3 ==0` and then checking `n%3==0`

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities

1. `n` is already a multiple of three
2. `n` is one less than a multiple of three
3. `n` is one more than a multiple of three

You can handle all cases by computing the remainder modulo 3, and then adjusting `n` if necessary, e.g.

```
// compute the remainder modulo 3
int remain = n % 3;

// adjust n if necessary
if ( remain == 2 )
    n++;
else if ( remain == 1 )
    n--;

// print the result
printf( "%d", n );
```

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, you could write it in a much simpler way:

```
switch(n % 3) {
{
    case 0: printf("%d", n); break;
    case 1: printf("%d", n - 1); break;
    case 2: printf("%d", n + 1); break;
}
```

Or you can write a one-liner:

```
printf("%d", n % 3 == 0 ? n : (n % 3 == 1 ? n - 1 : n + 1));
```

Comment: One liner is wrong I guess It will not print what question expected here.

Comment: @punitvara Why? It does the same thing as the `switch` statement above.

Comment: In question he mentioned to search nearest number not to check number itself. So I build you should not consider n%3 == 0 in both the case . Apart from that I appreciate your answer its looks fine :-)

Comment: @punitvara When `n` is an integer divisible by 3 (for example, 9), then what should be the nearest multiple of 3?

Comment: 6 and 12... I may be not write but frankly I am asking you :-).If somebody ask you "who is standing nearest to you?"  Would consider yourself as nearest ?

Comment: @punitvara Bad analogy. Nearest integer means the integer at the smallest distance, in that case the answer would be 9, where the distance is 0. Also, saying "6 and 12" is ambiguous.

Comment: I agree with you :-) . Thanks for clearing a silly doubt

Answer (score 0):

So, If I understand the question correctly, you need to check which number, of `(n, n+1, n-1)` is divisible by 3, and print that value.

Check below code:

```
n++; // start from n+1

/* If "n+1" is divisible, directly print it. Else "n", else "n-1" */

if (n%3!=0 ) // Check if n+1 is divisible by 3
{
    n--;

    if (n%3!=0 ) // Check if "n" is divisible by 3
        n--; // If not, "n-1" is the answer
}

printf("%d", n); // Print it
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly for example if user entered number 7 then program has to check whether(7-1) or (7+1) is divisible by 3. You can do it as follow:

```
n= some value
if(n%3 == 0)
printf("%d",n);
else if ((n+1)%3 == 0)     /* given number + 1 is divisible by 3 ? */
printf("%d",n+1);     /*if yes then print that divisible number */   
else if ((n-1)%3 == 0)     /*Given number -1 is divisible by 3? */ 
printf("%d",n-1);     /* if yes then print that divisible number */
```

If your question is to check continuously increment or the number and check which nearest is divisible then you have to use any loop. `if` will not be useful in that case.